# Mails from my server go to spam - how do I set up a rDNS and DKIM?

Tags: email, dns, dkim, email-spam, reverse-dns

I have a website setup on a hosting provider and now when any mails are sent from it, they go to spam in gmail (from field looks like this: *contact@mydomain.com via webserver.offshore-hosting-service.com*).

So i used mail-tester.com to test and I received a score of 7.7/10.

**A few things still needed fixing:**

1) rDNS: Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
This may be a false-positive, please check the reverse DNS test below to confirm or not this issue

2) DKIM: Your message is not signed with DKIM

3) DMARC: You do not have a DMARC record

**So I did the following (data has been obscured):**

1) I created a PTR DNS entry for rDNS like this):

> 30.61.2.94.in-addr.arpa PTR mydomain.com

2) DKIM:

> **Could someone help me figure out how to do this?**

3) DMARC:

> _dmarc.mydomain.com   TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"

After a day, I ran another mail-tester test and still got the same issues. What have I done wrong?

The one part I cannot figure out even after googling is how to setup the DKIM. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

DKIM setup is quite simple Follow the below steps -

1. First step is to create a SSH keypair. For Windows you can use PUTTYGen and for Linux and Mac, you can use ssh-keygen, [See this for details on how to generate](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)
2. Placing the public key as a TXT record for your domain in the DNS settings, depending on your DNS provider the steps of placing a TXT record may vary.
3. Generating and saving the signature, so that it can be used while sending mails in the headers.
4. Validate the DKIM.

[Follow this article for detailed link on each step.](https://www.mailjet.com/blog/news/setting-up-dkim-step-by-step-a7d0a0ec-c4aa-4b5b-aeb5-a06361aa2e51/)